# Packaging dependent jars with Bazel

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to build a relatively self-contained release package (let's say it's a tarball, but could be a RPM/Deb) that contains both my code (which is packaged into a jar), as well as jars my code was compiled with and uses at runtime. (Let's say those are the same set for simplicity.)

I've got MyPackage (which has a bunch of .java files) and let's say it directly depends on external jars A and B, and B depends on external jar C. I get A, B, and C from maven_jars.

I've already set up rules like this:

In MyPackage/BUILD:

```
java_library(
    name = "MyPackage",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/java/**/*.java"]),
    deps = ["//MyPackage/artifacts:compile_jars"],
)
```

and in MyPackage/artifacts/BUILD:

```
java_library(
    name = "compile_jars",
    visibility = ["//MyPackage:__pkg__"],
    exports = ["libdeps_A", "libdeps_B"]
)
java_library(
    name = "libdeps_A",
    exports = ["@org.someone.A//jar"],
)
java_library(
    name = "libdeps_B",
    exports = ["@org.secondparty.B//jar", ":libdeps_C"],
)
java_library(
    name = "libdeps_C",
    exports = ["@org.thirdperson.C//jar"],
)
```

However, the built libMyPackage.jar (as expected) doesn't contain the files from libdeps_[ABC], it only contains the .class files from things in MyPackage's src/main/java.

I've got another rule that successfully uses :MyPackage to put it in my tarball's lib/ dir.

My question is if there is some way to address the set of files (jars) that comes from traversing down the //MyPackage/artifacts:compile_jars rule so I can put them in the tar archive too.

This seems very similar to what the java_binary's _deploy.jar implicit output target does. I don't think I can use that, though, because my entry point doesn't have a "main" routine. (It's using onStart from Google Play)

I could certainly write some automation that would make another form of the //MyPackage/artifacts:compile_jars target out of the information that's in MyPackage/artifacts/BUILD, but I wonder if I'm re-inventing a wheel?

Thanks, Sean

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge there isn't a ubiquotous tool to do this.

We had the exact same problem (we create a jar-ball which contains the main jar, the full transitive closure, config files and some more)- What we ended up doing was writing our own solution which was inspired by [JarCreator](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/java_tools/buildjar/java/com/google/devtools/build/buildjar/jarhelper/JarCreator.java) (but written from scratch since we needed other features and didn't need some of their features and we prefer scala).

As another reference you can see rules_scala ([_build_deployable](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_scala/blob/8739e01bb784ec74c1e79c84f6883a349791ce08/scala/scala.bzl#L310)) which implements a deploy jar in skylark (presumably it will be easier to copy from than the native rules).

One more hint indicating this problem being un-solved is this bazel issue: [Add zip directory skylark action](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/2414)